# Removing hover event for click, then binding it again

Tags: jquery, click, hover, jquery-animate, unbind

I have a div called `#footer`, whose margin is animated using jQuery to slide it up when a user hovers over it. Inside `#footer` is a `div` called `#toggle`, which animates the footer back down again when clicked.

It all works fine except that when `#toggle` is clicked and `#footer` has animated back down, if I move the mouse it triggers the hover again, even though the mouse isn't over `#footer` anymore. It's driving me crazy!

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('#footer').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, "slow");
    $('#toggle').addClass('expanded'); 
});

$('#toggle').click(function(){ 
    $('#footer').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "-120px"}, "slow");
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
});
```

What I need I think is to unbind the hover event when it's done, and rebind it when `#toggle` is clicked. Maybe? But I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Use the `mouseenter` event instead of `hover`. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Accepted as you got it fixed first, by about a minute! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) event instead of [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover).

Using [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) with a single argument will trigger the function on both [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave).

> hover( handlerInOut(eventObject)  )

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only supplying one parameter to the `hover()` event, that will be called on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. If you change it to use `mouseenter()` it should work properly.

```
$('#footer').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, "slow");
    $('#toggle').addClass('expanded'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To unbind/rebind, declare the anonymous function elsewhere (and give it a name), then pass it in as a parameter:

```
function footerHover() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, "slow");
    $('#toggle').addClass('expanded');
    $(this).unbind('hover');
}
$('#footer').hover(footerHover);

$('#toggle').click(function(){
    $('#footer').hover(footerHover);
    $('#footer').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "-120px"}, "slow");
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
});
```

You could also try binding hover with two functions (as that's how hover was meant to be used):

```
$(selector).hover(functionWhileHovering, functionWhenNotHovering);
```

More specifically:

```
$('#footer').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "0px"}, "slow");
    $('#toggle').addClass('expanded');
    $(this).unbind('hover');
}, function () {
    $('#footer').stop(true, true).animate({"margin-bottom": "-120px"}, "slow");
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
});
```